# How to insert grouped median segments in violin plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to insert median lines for factor levels into a violin plot in `ggplot2`. Here's some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(12)
FactorVar <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 500, replace = T)
NumericVar <- abs(rnorm(500))
df <- data.frame(FactorVar, NumericVar)
```

To get the grouped medians I use `tapply`:

```
medians <- tapply(df$NumericVar, df$FactorVar, FUN = median)
```

And this is the code for the plot. As can be seen, I'm inserting each median line individually. That's cumbersome and uneconomical:

```
library(ggplot2)    
g <- 
  ggplot(data = df, 
         aes(x = FactorVar, y = NumericVar, fill = FactorVar)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "count", trim = F, adjust = 0.75) +
  geom_point(aes(y = NumericVar), 
             position = position_jitter(width = .15), size = 0.9, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(NumericVar), color = "blue", size = 0.8, linetype = 4) +
  geom_segment(x = 0.5, xend = 1.5, y= medians[1],  yend = medians[1], color = "red", linetype = 2) +
  geom_segment(x = 1.5, xend = 2.5, y = medians[2], yend = medians[2], color = "red", linetype = 2) +
  geom_segment(x = 2.5, xend = 3.5, y = medians[3], yend = medians[3], color = "red", linetype = 2) +
  geom_segment(x = 3.5, xend = 4.5, y = medians[4], yend = medians[4], color = "red", linetype = 2) +
  geom_segment(x = 4.5, xend = 5.5, y = medians[5], yend = medians[5], color = "red", linetype = 2) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_gray(); g
```

How can the median segments be inserted in a **single** command? Also, observe how the median line for factor `A` is thinner than the others? Why's that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method (that simplifies the +/- axis) would be to facet it. Before, though, we'll need to put the medians into a frame, preferably with the same grouping factors as the original.

```r
mediansdf <- data.frame(FactorVar=names(medians), NumericVar=medians)

g <- 
  ggplot(data = df, 
         aes(x = FactorVar, y = NumericVar, fill = FactorVar)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "count", trim = F, adjust = 0.75) +
  geom_point(aes(y = NumericVar), 
             position = position_jitter(width = .15), size = 0.9, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(NumericVar), color = "blue", size = 0.8, linetype = 4) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_gray() +
  facet_grid(FactorVar~., scales="free") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.5, xend = 1.5, yend = NumericVar), color = "red", linetype = 2, data = mediansdf)
g
```

[image: ggplot faceted violins]

This example reused the `y` aesthetic, but since we have a different frame, we could easily use different names (and specify them within `aes(...)`. One advantage to using the same variable names is (in my opinion) clearer *declarative* code.

Since the `facet_grid` adds the factor label on the right side, you likely could remove it from the axis. Note, if you do not use `scales="free"`, then you'll see all factors in each facet, which is distracting and unnecessary.

The reason I am suggesting facets is that it makes the `x` and `xend` simple and relative to a single violin, so 0.5 to 1.5; otherwise, as you saw, there is some assumption on which is going with which integer placement.

Last, the appearance of thinner red lines for me was while looking at the raster plot window. If you save to vector-based format (e.g., PDF), the lines appear to be the same thickness.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful and knowledgable. Just a tiny tweak: how can the factor labels on the left of the plot be removed or suppressed? (They are redundant given the facet grid.)

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot.